# Discord.js How to list the display names of all members with a specific role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a command that currently gives a count of how many people have a specific role. That functions properly. I am attempting to make a subcommand of that command that will list the members who have that role and I can get it to list their names as usernames, but I'm looking for it to list it as a display name instead.

This is the code that currently works

```
let nameList= message.guild.roles.resolve('Role-ID').members.map(m=>m.user.username).join('\n');
```

The "Role-ID is the actual ID in my code. I know that the displayName is a property of the GuildMember but I don't know how to integrate it here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but instead of deleting my post I figured I would post the solution.

All I needed to do was change .user.username to .displayName

```
let nameList= message.guild.roles.resolve('Role-ID').members.map(m=>m.user.username).join('\n');
```